# Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'Alias"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to delete from my object key recipients then add recipients key but with new values.

This looks to works fine:

```
this.alias.forEach((key) => {
      delete key["recipients"];
      key["recipients"] = this.newRecipients;
    })
```

But I got error:

> Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'Alias'.

This is my Alias model:

```
export interface Alias {
    nr?: number;
    local_part?: string;
    domain?: string;
    recipients?: string;
}
```

and there is declaration:

```
alias: Alias = {};
```

How should it be?

Comment: If you want to use `forEach`, `alias` needs to be an array.

Comment: What you mean by "_This looks to works fine_" & then "_But I got error_" ?

Comment: @palaѕн - I suspect the OP meant "It looks to me like this should work, but I get an error."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `alias` is not an array (or `NodeList` or similar), which is why it doesn't have `forEach`. But you don't need `forEach`, there's no reason for looping in your code.

You also don't need to delete a property before changing its value. Just assign to it directly:

```
this.alias.recipients = this.newRecipients;
```

You may be used to languages where you had to do things like deleting strings or similar for memory management reasons (`new` and `delete` in C++, for instance). JavaScript's [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator is not at all like the `delete` operator in those other languages; it serves a completely different purpose. (It removes a property from an object — something you almost never need to do.) It **isn't** for memory management. JavaScript is a garbage-collected language, you don't have to tell it when to remove something from memory, it does that when it sees that nothing refers to that thing anymore.

Also note there's no reason to use brackets notation and a string, you can use literal notation as above.

Comment: but then this.alias still got old values from backend. Instead of newRecipients

Comment: @MarcinDomorozki - I see you accepted the answer about an hour after your comment above, so I guess you realized that the old recipients *aren't* kept?

Comment: I just createad new Object :)

Comment: @MarcinDomorozki - There's no reason to do that. The line of code in the answer **does** replace the value of the `recipients` property.

Comment: but If I want to do console.log this.alis i still got old value